# where i can find the RDP 7 OCX

Tags: vb6, visual-c++

Can anybody tell me the link form, where I can download the RDP 7 OCX that will give me the features of RDP 7 client, such as bi-directional audio, Aero theme etc?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be included in the [client](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/results.aspx?pocId=&freetext=969084&DisplayEnglishAlso=on&DisplayLang=en)? As to how to use it - I have never used this library myself. I'm not sure what level of use you are asking about, but you add a reference to the mstscax.dll in the same way you do any other ActiveX DLL. It should already should already be in the **References** window as **Microsoft Terminal Services Control Type Library**. If not, just browse to the DLL and add it. If you are asking how to use it to connect to a remote desktop here is a simple example:

```
Private WithEvents rdp As MSTSCLib.MsRdpClient2

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Set rdp = New MSTSCLib.MsRdpClient2
   rdp.Server = "192.168.1.8"
   rdp.UserName = <username>
   rdp.UserName = <password>
   rdp.Connect
End Sub
```

Comment: i have update the windows xp client to 7 there there is feature of audio recoding and sound redirecting feature but i want to use RDP client 7 in my application. can u tell from where i can find it currently i m using rdp activeX 5.2 which is old version.

Comment: A quick look at Microsoft's download page shows version 5.2.3790. If that is the version you have then it does not look like they have released an update yet.

Comment: i have see the version of mstscax.dll 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)

i m using windows xp sp3 update RDP to RDP 7.
can u tell me hov to use it in vc6 or vb6 any one.